# Programme which stops without errors or warnings before entering the function

Tags: c, algorithm, long-running-processes

Please help! After I run my programme, it does neither breaks, nor any errors or warnings appear and debugger stops in exactly the same moment, before it should approach  function - "stworz_inaczej". What's wrong with that? Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

void stworz (int tablica[][6]);
int zablokowany (int tablica[][6], int ind1, int ind2);
int otoczony (int tablica[][6], int ind1, int ind2, int strona);
void stworz_inaczej (int tablica[][6]);
int sprawdz (int tablica[][6]);
void wypisz (int tablica[][6]);

int main()
{
    int wybor;
    int tablica[6][6];

    printf("Ktora metode wybierasz?");
    scanf("%d", &wybor);
    system("cls");
    do{
        if (wybor == 1)
            stworz(tablica);
        if (wybor == 2)
            stworz_inaczej(tablica);
        printf("------------\n\n");
    } while(sprawdz(tablica));
    wypisz(tablica);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void stworz (int tablica[][6]){
    int i, j;
    int ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4;
    int kulka = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            tablica[i][j] = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < rand() % 18 + 1; ++i){
        do
        {
            ind1 = rand() % 6;
            ind2 = rand() % 6;
            ind3 = rand() % 6;
            ind4 = rand() % 6;
        } while((ind1 == ind3 && ind2 == ind4) || (tablica[ind1][ind2] != 0 || tablica[ind3][ind4] != 0));
        tablica[ind1][ind2] = tablica[ind3][ind4] = kulka;
        kulka++;
    }
}

int sprawdz (int tablica[][6]){
    int i, j;
    int czy_dobrze_1 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            if(tablica[i][j] != 0){
                if(i - 1 >= 0)
                    if(tablica[i][j] == tablica[i-1][j] || tablica[i-1][j] == 0)
                        czy_dobrze_1 = 1;
                if(czy_dobrze_1 == 0 && j + 1 < 6)
                    if(tablica[i][j] == tablica[i][j+1] || tablica[i][j+1] == 0)
                        czy_dobrze_1 = 1;
                if(czy_dobrze_1 == 0 && i + 1 < 6)
                    if(tablica[i][j] == tablica[i+1][j] || tablica[i+1][j] == 0)
                        czy_dobrze_1 = 1;
                if(czy_dobrze_1 == 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
                    if(tablica[i][j] == tablica[i][j-1] || tablica[i][j-1] == 0)
                        czy_dobrze_1 = 1;
            }

    if (czy_dobrze_1 == 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int zablokowany (int tablica[][6], int ind1, int ind2){
    int czy_wejsc = 1;

    if (ind1 - 1 >= 0)
        if (tablica[ind1 - 1][ind2] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind1 + 1 < 6)
        if (tablica[ind1 + 1][ind2] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind2 - 1 >= 0)
        if (tablica[ind1][ind2 - 1] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind2 + 1 < 6)
        if (tablica[ind1][ind2 + 1] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;

    if (czy_wejsc == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (czy_wejsc == 1)
        return 1;
}

int otoczony (int tablica[][6], int ind1, int ind2, int strona){
    int czy_wejsc = 1;

    if (ind1 - 1 >= 0 && strona != 3)
        if (tablica[ind1 - 1][ind2] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind1 + 1 < 6 && strona != 1)
        if (tablica[ind1 + 1][ind2] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind2 - 1 >= 0 && strona != 2)
        if (tablica[ind1][ind2 - 1] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;
    if (ind2 + 1 < 6 && strona != 4)
        if (tablica[ind1][ind2 + 1] == 0)
            czy_wejsc = 0;

    if (czy_wejsc == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (czy_wejsc == 1)
        return 1;
}

void stworz_inaczej (int tablica[][6]){
    int i, j, ile_pol = 0, kulka = 0, gdzie, juz = 0, nastepny, koniec;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            tablica[i][j] = 0;

     do{
         koniec = 1;
         kulka ++;
         do{
             i = rand() % 6;
             j = rand() % 6;
         } while(tablica[i][j] != 0 || (zablokowany(tablica, i, j) == 1));
         tablica[i][j] = kulka;
         ile_pol++;
         do{
             nastepny = rand() % 2;
             if(tablica[i-1][j] == 0 && otoczony(tablica, i-1, j, 1) == 1){
                 tablica[i-1][j] = kulka;
                 i--;
                 ile_pol++;
                 nastepny = 0;
                 }
             else if(tablica[i][j+1] == 0 && otoczony(tablica, i, j+1, 2) == 1){
                 tablica[i][j+1] = kulka;
                 j++;
                 ile_pol++;
                 nastepny = 0;
                 }
             else if(tablica[i+1][j] == 0 && otoczony(tablica, i+1, j, 3) == 1){
                 tablica[i+1][j] = kulka;
                 i++;
                 ile_pol++;
                 nastepny = 0;
             }
             else if(tablica[i][j-1] == 0 && otoczony(tablica, i, j-1, 4) == 1){
                 tablica[i][j-1] = kulka;
                 j--;
                 ile_pol++;
                 nastepny = 0;
                 }
             else{
                 do{
                     gdzie = rand() % 4 + 1;
                     switch(gdzie)
                     {
                         case 1:
                             if(i-1 < 0 || tablica[i-1][j] != 0)
                                 break;
                             else {
                                 tablica[i-1][j] = kulka + 20;
                                 i--;
                                 ile_pol++;
                                 juz = 1;
                                 break;
                             }
                         case 2:
                             if(j+1 > 5 || tablica[i][j+1] != 0)
                                 break;
                             else {
                                 tablica[i][j+1] = kulka + 20;
                                 j++;
                                 ile_pol++;
                                 juz = 1;
                                 break;
                             }
                         case 3:
                             if(i+1 > 5 || tablica[i+1][j] != 0)
                                 break;
                             else {
                                 tablica[i+1][j] = kulka + 20;
                                 i++;
                                 ile_pol++;
                                 juz = 1;
                                 break;
                             }
                         case 4:
                             if(j-1 < 0 || tablica[i][j-1] != 0)
                                 break;
                             else {
                                 tablica[i][j-1] = kulka + 20;
                                 j--;
                                 ile_pol++;
                                 juz = 1;
                                 break;
                             }
                     }
                 } while(juz == 0);
                 nastepny = rand() % 2;
             }
         } while (nastepny == 1);
         tablica[i][j] = kulka;
         for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
             for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
                 if (zablokowany(tablica, i, j) == 0)
                     koniec = 0;
     } while(ile_pol <= 36 && koniec == 0);
     for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
         for (j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
             if (tablica[i][j] >= 20)
                 tablica[i][j] = 0;
}

void wypisz (int tablica[][6]){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<6; ++i){
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<6; ++j)
            printf("%d\t", tablica[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally set a breakpoint?

Comment: ok, I found the problem. It was variable "nastepny", which value was twice times changed by function rand(), every time the loop repeated, and this variable was also the condition for the loop...
Ty Keyser:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an infinite loop, that's why you didn't see anything on the screen. The error was at the outer do ... while clause in *stworz_inaczej* function.

Just replace this one:

`while(ile_pol <= 36 && koniec == 0);`

with this one - then the code should work

`while(ile_pol <= 36 && koniec != 0);`